# Sublime 3: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'update_phantoms_only'

Tags: sublimetext3

After updating to newest Sublime 3: 3170

I noticed this odd behavior. When I run build from sublime, it runs fine, but if running the build I open any file in sublime, I get this as output:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'update_phantoms_only'
[cmd: None]
[dir: /home/oerp/odoo11/enterprise/quality/models]
[path: /home/oerp/bin:/home/oerp/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
[Finished]
```

This is very annoying, because it overwrites whats on build log.

Does anyone know why this is happening? (it was not the case in previous sublime 3 releases).

My build config:

```
{
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
            "name": "Odoo Run",
        "shell_cmd": "python3 ~/openerp/scripts/odoo-run/run.py 11 -p 8069 --addons-path=~/odo11/source/my_project -d my_db",
            "syntax": "Packages/Makefile/Make Output.sublime-syntax",
        }
    ],
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/home/oerp/odoo11/source/remeksi"
        },
        {
            "path": "/home/oerp/odoo11/odoo"
        },
        {
            "path": "/home/oerp/odoo11/enterprise"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm having this problem as well; just asked about it in the forum: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/--init---got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-update-phantoms-only/36735

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you happen to have SublimeANSI installed? There's a new release in the last hour(!) or so that references this issue: https://github.com/aziz/SublimeANSI/pull/49

After updating that package via Package Control I'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: Yes i do. Yeah read that it is related. Ill try to update too. Though for some reason uninstalling pep8 also helped.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an issue at https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/2303#issuecomment-387695179

It seems it was related somehow with `pep8` (don't know if this helps everyone having same error). Sublime was giving me warning to start using `pycodestyle` (even though I had it installed already), but after I removed `pep8` and restarted sublime, this problem of raising error in build output has gone.

Though now I get warning that SublimeLinter can't find `pep8`, but linting still seems to work (probably uses `pycodestyle` now).